# d3.js v4 change line to bar chart

Tags: d3.js, svg

I'm trying to convert the line graph to bar, I'm having trouble understanding where I'm making the error. I'm using d3.js v4.

This line of code displays code that works for line area:

```
var area = d3.area()
          .x(function(d) { return   time_scale(d['timestamp'])+6.5; })
          .y0(-80+width -max_y)
          .y1(function(d) { return measure_scale(+d[field]); })
          .curve(d3.curveStep)
          ;

// append a SVG path that corresponds to the line chart
d3.select('#chart').append("path")
         .datum(neigh_data)
         .attr("class", "area")
         .attr("d", area)
         .attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin + ', -15)')

         ;
```

This line of code does not work for bars (it looks like the height of the rectangle is not correct, and I'm not using the color fill):

```
   d3.select('#chart').selectAll(".bar").append("path")
  .datum(neigh_data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .attr("x", function(d) { return   time_scale(d['timestamp']); })
  .attr("y", function(d,i) { return measure_scale(+d[field]); })
  .attr("width", time_scale.bandwidth())    
  .attr("height", function (d,i) {  return height -  measure_scale(+d[field]); }) 
       ;
```

I'm really messing around with something.

Comment: I don't think you should be using datum here -- try data instead

Comment: It worked!!! thank you so much!!

Comment: I used datum because I use maps and bubble together.. the problem is to remove the "path"     var drawChart = function(field) {
    // remove the previous chart

              d3.select('#chart').select('.x.axis').remove();     
              d3.select('#chart').select('path').remove();
              d3.select('#chart').selectAll("g").remove();

Comment: d3.select('#chart').selectAll("*").remove();  solved the problem... thanks friend..